# How to conditionally update a resource in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

Seems it's common practice to make use of **count** on a resource to conditionally create it in Terraform using a ternary statement.

I'd like to conditionally update an AWS Route 53 entry based on a **push_to_prod** variable. Meaning I don't want to delete the resource if I'm not pushing to production, I only want to update it, or leave the CNAME value as it is.

Has anyone done something like this before in Terraform?

Comment: It might help if you more fully explained what you're trying to do here and why. If you could provide a [mcve] and explain how that doesn't work how you want then that would also help people answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Currently as it stands interpolation syntax isn't supported in lifecycle tags. You can read more [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#lifecycle). Which will make this harder because you could use the "Prevent Destroy". However, without more specifics I am going to take my best guess on how to get your there.

I would use the [allow_overwrite](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html#allow_overwrite) property on the Route53 record and set that based on your flag. That way if you are pushing to prod you can set it it false. Which should trigger creating a new one. I haven't tested that.

Also note that if you don't make any changes to the Route53 resource it should trigger any changes in Terraform to be applied. So updating any part of the record will trigger the deployment.

You may want to combine this with some lifecycle events, but I don't have enough time to dig into that specific resource and how it happens.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried out **allow_overwrite** and that did work, until I went to destroy my environment, that resource was planned to be deleted. What I ended up doing was using a **null_resource** with a ternary to set **count**, that resource had a **provisioner** which executed a shell script. Maybe not perfect, but it works out.

Answer (score 1):

Two examples I can think of are:

`type = "${var.push_to_prod == "true" ? "CNAME" : var.other_value}"` - this will have a fixed `other_value`, there is no way to have terraform "ignore" the resource once it's being managed by terraform.

or

`type = "${var.aws_route53_record_type}"` and you can have `dev.tfvars` and `prod.tfvars`, with `aws_route53_record_type` defined as whatever you want for `dev` and `CNAME` for prod.

The thing is with what you're trying to do, "I only want to update it, or leave the CNAME value as it is.", that's not how terraform works. Terraform either manages the resource for you or it doesn't. If it's managing it, it'll update the resource based on the config you've defined in your `.tf` file. If it's not managing the resource it won't modify it. It sounds like what you're really after is the second solution where you pass in two different configs from your `.tfvars` file into your `.tf` file and based off the different configs, different resources are created. You can couple this with `count` to determine if a resource should be created or not.